# Find the $Z$-transform of $\sin (\alpha k), k \ge0$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, trigonometric-series, z-transform

Find the $Z$-transform of $\sin (\alpha k), k \ge0$

**Solution**

> [image]

Could anyone please explain how we got the second step (in terms of $e$ and $i$) after writing it in basic $Z$-transform notation? And how it was simplified? I can't follow.

Comment: **Hint:** $e^{ix} = \cos x + i\sin x$. I trust you can go on from here

Comment: For a simpler solution, find the Z-transform of $e^{i\alpha k}$ then extract the imaginary part.

Answer (score 0):

This result can be found in any introductory signal processing book, but I'll post the solution of a closely related problem here.

Given $f(k) = e^{i\alpha k}$, its $Z$-transform is
$$
\mathcal{Z}\{f(k)\} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} f(k)z^{-k} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}e^{i\alpha k}z^{-k} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(e^{i\alpha}z^{-1})^k = 1 + e^{i\alpha}z^{-1} + (e^{i\alpha}z^{-1})^2 + \dots = F(z),
$$
for $|z| < 1$. To find a closed-form for $F(z)$, multiply it by $e^{i\alpha}z^{-1}$ and note
$$
e^{i\alpha}z^{-1}F(z) = e^{i\alpha}z^{-1} + (e^{i\alpha}z^{-1})^2 + (e^{i\alpha}z^{-1})^3 + \dots = F(z) - 1\\
F(z)(1 - e^{i\alpha}z^{-1}) = 1\\
F(z) = {1 \over 1 - e^{i\alpha}z^{-1}}\cdot {1-e^{-i\alpha}z^{-1} \over 1 - e^{-i\alpha}z^{-1}} = {1 - e^{-i\alpha}z^{-1} \over 1 - z^{-1}(e^{i\alpha} + e^{-i\alpha}) + z^{-2}}.
$$
Using $e^{ix} = \cos x + i\sin x$,
$$
F(z) = {1 - z^{-1}(\cos\alpha - i\sin\alpha) \over 1 - 2z^{-1}\cos\alpha + z^{-2}}.\tag1
$$
The $Z$-transforms of $\cos(\alpha k)$ and $\sin(\alpha k)$ can be trivially found from $(1)$.